# Returning a nullable DateTime in LINQ2SQL

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql, nullable

The following LINQ2SQL query is throwing an error stating that it can't put a `null` into a `DateTime` or more specifically

> The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.DateTime which is a non-nullable value type

here is the code, the error appears on the LINQ line, i.e. the `d = (from...` line.

```
internal static DateTime? GetDateOfLastSkew(DateTime date, DateTime expiry)
{
    object d;
    using (SAFEX db = new SAFEX())
    {
        d = (from skew in db.Skew
             where skew.CalibrationDate.Date <= date.Date
                && skew.Expiry.Date == expiry.Date
             select skew.CalibrationDate).Max();
    }

    return d == DBNull.Value ? null : d as DateTime?;
}
```

But `d` is an `object` so it can't have trouble assigning `null` to it which means it must be happening somewhere inside that LINQ query.

what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast result `select` to nullable:

```
d = (from skew in db.Skew
     where skew.CalibrationDate.Date <= date.Date
        && skew.Expiry.Date == expiry.Date
     select ((DateTime?)skew.CalibrationDate)).Max();

return d;
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Will accept when enough time has elapsed.

Answer (score 2):

When called on a collection of non-nullable types like `DateTime`, `Max()` will return a value of that non-nullable type, or throw if there are no items in the collection.

`d` might be an object, but the only thing you tried to assign to it was a `DateTime`, so the only thing you are going to get out is a `DateTime` or a `DateTime?` (you can unbox to either). It's never going to be set to `DBNull.Value` (which has little use in linq, it's mostly for the lower level of dealing with databases directly).

If you know there will always be at least one matching row, then forget about `d` and just obtain the `DateTime` and let it be cast to `DateTime?` on return:

```
internal static DateTime? GetDateOfLastSkew(DateTime date, DateTime expiry)
{
  using (SAFEX db = new SAFEX())
  {
    return (from skew in db.Skew
         where skew.CalibrationDate.Date <= date.Date
            && skew.Expiry.Date == expiry.Date
         select skew.CalibrationDate).Max(); // Max returns a DateTime.
  }
}
```

If you don't know there'll always be at least one match, then cast to `DateTime?` in the selcet, so that `Max()` is now working on a nullable type and can return null when appropriate:

```
internal static DateTime? GetDateOfLastSkew(DateTime date, DateTime expiry)
{
  using (SAFEX db = new SAFEX())
  {
    return (from skew in db.Skew
         where skew.CalibrationDate.Date <= date.Date
            && skew.Expiry.Date == expiry.Date
         select (DateTime?)skew.CalibrationDate).Max(); // Max returns a DateTime or null on no matches.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Can you call `return` inside the `using` with no problems? That's good to know if that's the case :)

Comment: That's pretty much the point of `using`, you can `return` or `throw` (whether directly, or indirectly) out of it or just reach the end, and the `IDispose.Dispose()` call it does for you gets done either way. (It is in fact syntactic sugar for a `try{…} finally{…}`).

Comment: (You can get problems if you return something that doesn't work after that `IDispose.Dispose()` was called, but that would also be true of using it after you'd left the `using` by reaching the end, too).